# Web Api 2 route configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

What is the difference and usage of each of the following code segments in web api 2
And I had another problem when I used controller name without action it works
but if I wrote  controller/action for example localhost:4434://pay/index it does not work and gave 404 page not found

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
               );
    }
}
```

and

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",

            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The first snippet of for web api and the second is for normal MVC. Both have the same route template so they conflict with each other. because Web API is usually registered before normal MVC. Routes follow a convention of first match wins. So all your routes will match the Web API route and never reach the MVC routes. The reason you usually see the API route prefixed with `api/...` is to avoid route conflicts because all the routes end up in the same route table.

Comment: OK thank you for this answer but I also wounder if this has anything to do with the ApiController vs Controller I mean does the first snippet matches only ApiController  and the second matches Controller @Nkosi

Comment: Yes the first will only look for ApiController but if it does not find any it wont move on to the Controllers because the route template has already matched the URL provided. Hence the not found error. It basically mean that *Yes I found a matching route but not a matching action to that route*